# How can I hide markers and markerclusters outside a specific zoom level in folium?

Tags: maps, markerclusterer, folium

Is it possible to hide a marker and markercluster on folium map in some specific zoom level?

My code needs to react to zoom change and decide what points I want to share and register/deregister them from the map.

I know that it is possible to do it with Leaflet using get.Zoom() and zoomend. As folium uses map from Leaflet I guess that is also possible to do it with folium, but I am not sure how to do it yet.

This is what I have so far (any idea on how to improve my code and make it "smarter" is also appreciated, I am just a beginner in Python):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn
import folium
import mplleaflet
import os
import json
from folium import plugins
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster
from folium import FeatureGroup, LayerControl, Map, Marker

df = pd.read_csv(r'Pakistan.csv')
data = df[['Latitude', 'Longitude']].values.tolist()

x = list(df['Latitude'])
y = list(df['Longitude'])
ID = list(df['S'])

latmean = df['Latitude'].mean()
lonmean = df['Longitude'].mean()

m = folium.Map(location=[latmean, lonmean], zoom_start= 10, zoom_control=True)
folium.TileLayer('openstreetmap').add_to(m)
folium.TileLayer('Stamen Terrain').add_to(m)

#Vega data
vis1 = os.path.join('data', 'vis1.json')

#Geojson Data
overlay = os.path.join('data', 'overlay.json')

#Distrital
fgDistrital = FeatureGroup(name='Distrital', control=True)
my_Circle1 = MarkerCluster().add_to(fgDistrital)
for i in range (1,4):
 folium.Marker(location=[x[i], y[i]], popup=str("Distrital")).add_to(my_Circle1)

#Polo
fgPolo = FeatureGroup(name = 'Polo', show=False)
my_Circle2 = MarkerCluster().add_to(fgPolo)
for i in range (5,8):
 folium.Marker(location=[x[i], y[i]], popup=folium.Popup(str("Polo"), max_width=450, show=True).add_child(folium.Vega(json.load(open(vis1)), width=450, height=250))).add_to(my_Circle2)

#Rota
fgRota = FeatureGroup(name='Rota', control=True)    
my_Circle3 = MarkerCluster().add_to(fgRota)
for i in range (9,20):
 folium.Marker(location=[x[i], y[i]], popup=str("Rota")).add_to(my_Circle3)

m.add_child(fgDistrital)
m.add_child(fgPolo)
m.add_child(fgRota)
folium.GeoJson(overlay, name = 'vis1').add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl(collapsed=True).add_to(m)
m.save('example.html')
```